# nginx gzip - Caching

Tags: nginx, compression, gzip, http-caching

In the nginx config, I have enabled gzip compression on and I have not enabled any caching headers.

By default, whether nginx compress only the first client request and store the compressed files in the cache or does it compress for all the requests. Thanks.